# How do I turn this into a while loop program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

The following code is a program for an assignment last week. The assignment was to create a program that you would enter information into as a cashier and it would total everything up for you based on the information entered. Part of this week's assignment is to enhance it so multiple items can be handled by the program, using a while loop. This improved program should output the total for all items.

This is an example of the output the professor is looking for.

```
Original ticket price: $100
Is this item reduced?y
Is this item taxable?y
Here is your bill
Orginal Price $100.00
Reduced Price $25.00
Final Price $75.00
7% Sales Tax $5.25
Total amount due $80.25

Original ticket price: $75
Is this item reduced?y
Is this item taxable?n
Here is your bill
Orginal Price $75.00
Reduced Price $18.75
Final Price $56.25
7% Sales Tax $0.00
Total amount due $56.25

Total amount due is $136.50
```

```
# Enter constants for sale & salesTax
SALE = .25
SALES_TAX = .07

# Enter the ticket price of the item
origPrice = float(input('Original ticket price or 0 to quit: $'))

# Is the item reduced? Y/y or N/n - use if/elif to determine salePrice
reduced = input('Is this item reduced?')

if reduced == 'Y' or  reduced == 'y':
    salePrice = origPrice * SALE

elif reduced == 'N' or reduced == 'n':
    salePrice = 0.00

# Enter constant for finalPrice = origPrice - salePrice
finalPrice = origPrice - salePrice

# Is the item taxable? Y/y or N/n - use if/elif to determine tax
taxable = input('Is this item taxable?')

if taxable == 'Y' or taxable == 'y':
    tax = finalPrice * SALES_TAX

elif taxable == 'N' or taxable == 'n':
    tax = 0.00

# Enter all Print Statements
print('Here is your bill')
print('Orginal Price $', format(origPrice, ',.2f'),sep='')
print('Reduced Price $', format(salePrice, ',.2f'),sep='')
print('Final Price $', format(finalPrice, ',.2f'),sep='')
print('7% Sales Tax $', format(tax, ',.2f'),sep='')
print('Total amount due $', format(finalPrice + tax, ',.2f'),sep='')
```

Comment: Well, are you able to write a while loop at all? Can you decide what the condition should be for the loop? Can you decide what should happen before the loop, during each iteration of the loop, and after the looping has completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! From the sample output that your professor gave you, it seems like you'll need to wrap your current code (excluding constant declarations) in a `while True` loop with the break condition, but also add another variable called `totalAmountDue`. This variable will be changed every time a new item is added. If you were to apply the changes, it should look like this:

```
# Enter constants for sale & salesTax
SALE = .25
SALES_TAX = .07

# Counter for the total amount of money from all items, this includes tax as well
totalAmountDue = 0

while True:
    # Enter the ticket price of the item
    origPrice = float(input('Original ticket price or 0 to quit: $'))

    # Breaks out of the loop once the user wants to quit
    if (origPrice == 0):
        break

    # Is the item reduced? Y/y or N/n - use if/elif to determine salePrice
    reduced = input('Is this item reduced?')

    if reduced == 'Y' or  reduced == 'y':
        salePrice = origPrice * SALE

    elif reduced == 'N' or reduced == 'n':
        salePrice = 0.00

    # Enter constant for finalPrice = origPrice - salePrice
    finalPrice = origPrice - salePrice

    # Is the item taxable? Y/y or N/n - use if/elif to determine tax
    taxable = input('Is this item taxable?')

    if taxable == 'Y' or taxable == 'y':
        tax = finalPrice * SALES_TAX

    elif taxable == 'N' or taxable == 'n':
        tax = 0.00

    # Adds the final price of this product to the total price of all items 
    totalAmountDue += finalPrice + tax

    # Enter all Print Statements
    print("Here's the breakdown for this item: ")
    print('Orginal Price $', format(origPrice, ',.2f'),sep='')
    print('Reduced Price $', format(salePrice, ',.2f'),sep='')
    print('Final Price $', format(finalPrice, ',.2f'),sep='')
    print('7% Sales Tax $', format(tax, ',.2f'),sep='')
    print('Total amount due $', format(finalPrice + tax, ',.2f'), "\n",sep='')

print("\nTotal amount due for all items: $", format(totalAmountDue, ',.2f'))
```

This is the output of the edited version:

```
Original ticket price or 0 to quit: $10
Is this item reduced?n 
Is this item taxable?y
Here's the breakdown for this item: 
Orginal Price $10.00
Reduced Price $0.00
Final Price $10.00
7% Sales Tax $0.70
Total amount due $10.70

Original ticket price or 0 to quit: $23123123123
Is this item reduced?n
Is this item taxable?y
Here's the breakdown for this item: 
Orginal Price $23,123,123,123.00
Reduced Price $0.00
Final Price $23,123,123,123.00
7% Sales Tax $1,618,618,618.61
Total amount due $24,741,741,741.61

Original ticket price or 0 to quit: $0

Total amount due for all items: $ 24,741,741,752.31
```

If you'd like to learn more about while loops in python, you can check out this link: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp

Comment: I could literally cry right now. Thank you so so much! I've been staring at this and trying different things for about 3 hours and nothing was working. You're amazing.

Comment: No problem! Since this solved your problem, I'd appreciate it if you marked my answer as the one that solved your question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 100%. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Always nice to see people learn programming. Python is a great Lang and there's plenty of resources out there. Having said that, checkout the code below and if your interested seeing it run click the link below. Its' a Google Colab note book, it's pretty much a python env to develop from your browser.

```
  # Enter constants for sale & salesTax
SALE = .25
SALES_TAX = .07
Order = []
while True:
  # Enter the ticket price of the item
  tmp = float(input('Original ticket price or 0 to quit: $'))
  if 0 == tmp:
    break
  else:
    origPrice = tmp
  
  # Is the item reduced? Y/y or N/n - use if/elif to determine salePrice
  reduced = input('Is this item reduced?')

  if reduced == 'Y' or  reduced == 'y':
      salePrice = origPrice * SALE

  elif reduced == 'N' or reduced == 'n':
      salePrice = 0.00

  # Enter constant for finalPrice = origPrice - salePrice
  finalPrice = origPrice - salePrice

  # Is the item taxable? Y/y or N/n - use if/elif to determine tax
  taxable = input('Is this item taxable?')

  if taxable == 'Y' or taxable == 'y':
      tax = finalPrice * SALES_TAX

  elif taxable == 'N' or taxable == 'n':
      tax = 0.00

  result = (finalPrice + tax)
  Order.append(['Orginal Price ${0} '.format(origPrice, '.2f'), 'Reduced Price ${0} '.format(salePrice, '.2f'), 'Final Price ${0} '.format(finalPrice, '.2f'),
                '7% Sales Tax ${0} '.format(tax, '.2f'), 'Total amount due ${0} '.format(result, '.2f')])

# Enter all Print Statements
print('\n')
for i in Order: 
  print(i[0])
  print(i[1])
  print(i[2])
  print(i[3])
  print(i[4])
```

Link Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1S64fGVM1rQTv05rJBlvjOVrwHQFm8faK?usp=sharing

Senario One:
[image: OrgPrice: 100]

Comment: Thanks TheNeUpKID. That's not exactly what the professor is looking for. I can't yet embed images. But this is a sample output of what he's looking for...

Original ticket price: $100
Is this item reduced?y
Is this item taxable?y
Here is your bill
Orginal Price $100.00
Reduced Price $25.00
Final Price $75.00
7% Sales Tax $5.25
Total amount due $80.25

Original ticket price: $75
Is this item reduced?y
Is this item taxable?n
Here is your bill
Orginal Price $75.00
Reduced Price $18.75
Final Price $56.25
7% Sales Tax $0.00
Total amount due $56.25

Total amount due is $136.50

Comment: Updated with a screen shot. Though, I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Right. So he wants us to be able to enter multiple items, each one list the original price, reduced price, final price, tax and total, and then at the bottom of each of those statements list the sum of each of the total amount due for each item.

Comment: Hey @Laurie, I have updated my answer. If I understand correctly, I updated to include the values entered to be stored within a variable and then `append` into an array, this mean every iteration  receipt answers would be pushed on to the stack, this can lead to poor code practice if there's not type checking or input value checking, etc. Please keep in-mind that in programming there are many ways to answer a problem, it becomes more of a question of how efficient or memory consumption.